# Switching buffer to special mode or any mode?

Tags: buffers, major-mode

I have written some code to create a new buffer, it starts up in fundamental mode, the buffer is to display output from commands.

I am using this to create the buffer

```
(get-buffer-create "*My Buffer*")
```

Then I am trying to switch to and change the mode using this.

```
(display-buffer buffer-name)
(special-mode)
```

My understanding is that this should switch to the buffer and change the mode which is what actually happens with the added side effect the the original buffer I was using also switches to special-mode so both buffers end up in special-mode.

Am i doing this completely wrong ? how can i create a buffer for command output and change the mode of just that buffer ?

This is the working answer.

```
(display-buffer buffer-name)
(with-current-buffer buffer-name (special-mode))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docstring of `display-buffer` says (`C-h f display-buffer`):

> display-buffer is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `window.el'.
>
> It is bound to C-x 4 C-o.
>
> (display-buffer BUFFER-OR-NAME &optional ACTION FRAME)
>
> Display BUFFER-OR-NAME in some window, **without selecting it**.

You have to select the buffer for following operations to act on it.  See eg `set-buffer` or `with-current-buffer`.